# Json Serialization Exception

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

The relationship between models are: X has many Y; Y has many Z:

```
class X 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    IList<Y> Y { get; set; }
}

class Y
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    X x { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    IList<Z> Z { get; set; }
}

class Z
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    Y y { get; set; }
}

public class YBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    readonly IQuizRepository _quizRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IQuizRepository>();

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var y = (Y)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        if (problem.Chapter != null)
        {
            y.X = _quizRepository.getX(y.X.Id);
        }
        return y;
    }
}

public class ZBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{ 
    readonly IQuizRepository _quizRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IQuizRepository>();

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var z = (Z)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        if (z.Y != null)
        {
            z.Y = _quizRepository.getY(z.Y.Id);
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

My problem is that grid X and Y are populated but gird Z throws a `JsonSerializationException`.  Here is the action which populates grid Z and throws an exception:

```
public ContentResult Problems(JqInViewModel jqParams)
{
    var problems = _quizRepository.Problems(jqParams.page - 1, jqParams.rows, jqParams.sidx, jqParams.sord == "asc");

    var totalProblems = _quizRepository.TotalProblems(false);

    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        page = jqParams.page,
        records = totalProblems,
        rows = problems,
        total = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(totalProblems) / jqParams.rows)
    }, new CustomDateTimeConverter()), "application/json");
}
```

The problem is somwewhere with JSON; when I put `[JsonIgnore]` in class Z for debugging 
then the grid loads without an exception, otherwise it gives `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`.

```
class Z
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]          // this removes exception but then I cant bind y in grid
    Y y { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependencies in your models and you cannot JSON serialize such object graphs simply because the JSON format doesn't support it. You will have to rethink your models in such a way so that the circular dependency is broken. Think of what is the only information that you need to pass to the view and then flatten your domain models into a simple view model. Finally pass this flattened view model to the view.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I understood your point of simple view model and may be I can get my solution work but I dint understand that where is the circular dependency ? The relationship between models is simple x->y->z and I am using JsonIgnore to ensure that only one class among parent and child  is responsible for serializing the data. If you have time can you explain me this point.